# How to access maven repository from .m2 folder (local folder) in production?

Tags: maven, gradle, artifactory, maven-repository

I am working on one of google sdk project where to run that project smoothly I need to place the google sdk code in .m2 repository folder.

Everything is working good locally. Now I am moving my code to production.
Is there any chance of converting that repo to jar , artifactory or any other option to access that sdk in production.

Comment: Depends on your requirements: for a java app, http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/ could produce a zip/tar.gz with all that.

Comment: @NoDataFound my requirement is for Android application as working on google wallet stuff to integrate. I am looking for gradle project generation or to jar file.

Comment: Not much an user of gradle, but it exists: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

Comment: Assuming the current SDK project structure to be having the build files available as it's needed in Gradle, I believe the steps described in "https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Working+with+Gradle#WorkingwithGradle-RunningGradle" would help.